# Asp.net hosted Blazor app is producing way too many WASM files/objects in the Script Documents folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

When running from VS Community 2019 Preview 3, i see so many WASM related script documents, it seems to be a huge performance bottleneck.

Why are these WASM files being produced constantly at run-time, and how to disable/minimize this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Unclear: which Wasm (?) files, where do you see them, are they deployed at all?

Comment: Added screenshot of the files.

Comment: Getting better. But I'm still not convince about 'at runtime' or 'huge performance bottleneck'.